# IONIC 4 : Image from api loading failed on android release apk

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using ionic 4,and using cordova-plugin-advanced-http for reading data from api. when I'm trying to read images from API on debug mode,everything is working fine,but when I make released apk images are not displaying and I'm facing with 404 error. and the other hand I tried to install and configure cordova-plugin-whitelist as like as below but it's still not working.
config.xml

```
 <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <access origin="https://*.jomsave.com" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <access origin="content:///*" />
    <access origin="file:///*" />
```

index.html

```
<meta http-equiv=“Content-Security-Policy” content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

this issue is only appear in android and only when I'm building release apk and ios version is working fine

Comment: Finally I found the reason of the issue, it was because of ssl certificate. in Android release the image's url has been blocked by SystemWebViewClient , for solving this issue I found two way : first find the SSL issue on server and solve it or change one line of code.
check this link : 
http://ivancevich.me/articles/ignoring-invalid-ssl-certificates-on-cordova-android-ios/

Answer (score 1):

Try removing and then adding **cordova-plugin-whitelist** :

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Comment: I tried this many time , but it doesn't work. also I tried to make clean project and it's also not working ...

Comment: @user2642051 connect your phone to pc and debug in chrome .see the console what its showing

Comment: In debug time I don't get any error , even when I'm using --prod, this happening is only for --release ,resign and compressed apk. and the other hand IOS version is working fine.

Comment: @user2642051 on android --release are other api calls happening properly and receiving data ?

Comment: @user2642051 yes all api's (fetching and sending data) are working fine, the issue is just for image

Comment: Sorry were you able to resolve this issue? I'm going through the exact same. I found this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/image-dont-show-on-devices/104307/26 but I'm not sure if that cover your use case or mine since I'm not in charge of the backend on my team...

Comment: @JoseGeorges did you find a solution?